# Locally testing a Facebook app via OAuth login on Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am using `dev_appserver.py` to test my app locally.  However, I can't login to it because Facebook restricts logins to only the app URL I provide in the Facebook setup, which is `myappname.appspot.com`.

It doesn't look like there's a way to authorize secondary referrers for Facebook apps.  Are there any good workarounds for this?

My app relies almost entirely on Facebook data, so faking a login won't get me very far.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

option 1) Edit your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) so that your registered domain points to 127.0.0.1

option 2) Register a secondary app ID on facebook that you will use for development purposes.  Register this with the URL of localhost.  Then switch which app ID you use prior to deployment to your production server.

Given how common this problem is, it's shocking to me that the Facebook documentation isn't more explicit about the workaround.  Other OAuth providers aren't any better though...

Comment: Went with #2 and just added a debug flag that sets app ID/secret appropriately.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a note that wasn't immediately obvious to me: To make either of these solutions work, I had to change my application's port in the GAE Launcher to 80. Neither the Hosts file or the Facebook configuration allows port numbers to be specified.

Comment: I was able to include port in the site URL in my Facebook app settings, eg. http://localhost:8080/

Comment: @bfox how did you do that? if i try it with the launcher i get an error message that the port must be more than 1024